Installed Ubuntu 24.04 and dns_probe_finished_bad_config but ping 8.8.8.8 works
I just installed Ubuntu 24.04 and when I connect to the internet (via WiFi and ethernet) with chrome, I get
Dns_prob_finished_bad_config
Ping www.google.com
Doesn't work (temporary failure in name resolution)
But ping 8.8.8.8 works

sudo nano /etc/systemd/resolved.conf
then uncomment and set the DNL line:
[Resolve] DNS=8.8.8.8
restart systemd-resolved:
sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved
